# Reducing vacuum Einstein field equations to wave equations using wave coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

In a lot of research papers, authors claim that it is well know that in wave coordinates, Einstein field equations can be reduced to wave equations. But I did not find any reference. Can anybody suggest some good reference? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Googling a bit I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_coordinate_condition) which should be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look, for instance, at the books by Straumann [1, Section 5.1 and 5.3], Sean Carroll [2, Chapter 7, in particular Eq. 7.91 and the text leading up to it], or his lecture notes [3, Chapter 6], but this is really treated in most standard textbooks on general relativity.

It is important to note that the claim is in general only true for the **linearlized** field equations. The idea is to write the metric tensor as $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$, where $|h_{\mu\nu}|\ll 1$ is a small perturbation of the flat Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ (i.e. we consider only very small gravitational fields) and work to linear order in $h_{\mu\nu}$ and its derivatives. After working it all out, the linearlized Einstein equations then take the form.

\begin{align}
\label{eq:linearized_EFEs2}
G_{\mu\nu} = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(-\partial_\mu\partial_\nu h - \square h_{\mu\nu} + \partial_\nu\partial_\rho h^\rho_\mu + \partial_\mu\partial_\rho h^\rho_\nu + \eta_{\mu\nu}\left(\square h - \partial_\rho\partial_\sigma h^{\rho\sigma}\right)\right).
\end{align}

Now the trick is to show that, given any $h_{\mu\nu}$, one can always perform a suitable coordinate transformation (this context usually called a gauge transformation) such that in the new coordinates $h_{\mu\nu}$ satisfies

\begin{align}
\partial_\mu h^\mu{}_\lambda - \frac{1}{2}\partial_\lambda h = 0, \qquad h \equiv \eta^{\mu\nu}h_{\mu\nu}.
\end{align}

This gauge (i.e. choice of coordinates) goes by many names (Lorenz gauge, Einstein gauge, Hilbert gauge, de Donder gauge, Fock gauge). You can confirm that a lot of the terms in $G_{\mu\nu}$ then cancel each other, and we are left with

\begin{align}
G_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\square h_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}\square h\right).
\end{align}

The field equation $G_{\mu\nu} = \kappa T_{\mu\nu}$ thus reduces to

\begin{align}
\square h_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}\square h = -2\kappa T_{\mu\nu}.
\end{align}

In *vacuum* (i.e. $T_{\mu\nu}=0)$ the trace of this equation shows that $\square h =0$, and hence the vacuum field equation becomes

\begin{align}
\boxed{
\square h_{\mu\nu} = 0,}
\end{align}

which is a homogeneous wave equation for each component of the metric. If $T_{\mu\nu}\neq 0$ then one has to introduce the "trace-reversed" perturbation $\bar h_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu} - \tfrac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}h$, in term of which the field equations become

\begin{align}
\boxed{
\square \bar h_{\mu\nu}  = -2\kappa T_{\mu\nu},}
\end{align}

which is a classic inhomogeneous wave equation for each component of $\bar h_{\mu\nu}$.

[1] *Straumann, Norbert*, General relativity. With applications to astrophysics., Texts and Monographs in Physics. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-21924-2/hbk). xii, 674 p. (2004).

[2] *Carroll, Sean*, Spacetime and geometry. An introduction to general relativity, San Francisco, CA: Addison Wesley (ISBN 0-8053-8732-3). xiv, 513 p. (2004).

[3] [Sean Carrol's lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019)

**EDIT:** After posting the answer I realized there is also such a thing as nonlinear wave coordinates, which you might have meant. But well, let's hope this answer is useful for somebody nontheless.