# How to obtain reduced Einstein equations?

Tags: general-relativity

It is well known that in wave coordinates, vacuum Einstein field equations are equivalent to the following so called reduced Einstein equations:

$$R_{\mu\nu}+g_{\sigma(\mu}\Gamma_{,\nu)}^{\sigma}=0.$$

But I don't know how to show this fact. The following are my questions and I'd appreciated it if someone could please help.

1. What does the notation $g_{\sigma(\mu}\Gamma_{,\nu)}^{\sigma}$ mean?
2. How to show this well known fact? If it is not easy to type, a reference showing how to use wave coordinates to obtain reduced Einstein equations is also appreciated.

Comment: Similar question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4594121/949989). Did the references I gave in that comment help at all? Perhaps worth learning some basic GR first before going to the arcane subject of wave coordinates. Sean Carroll's Space Time book perhaps? It is well known that the notation $T_{(\mu\nu)}$ means [symmetrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_tensor): $T_{(\mu\nu)}=\frac{T_{\mu\nu}+T_{\nu\mu}}{2}\,.$

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Yes, it helps. Regarding the term $g_{\sigma(\mu}\Gamma^{\sigma}_{,\nu)}$, is it supposed to be written as $g_{\sigma(\mu\Gamma^{\sigma}_{,\nu})}$?

Comment: No! See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer is wrong because it lowered the index $\sigma$ which breaks the summation convention. [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/95138/304394) shows that only the two lower indices $\mu$ and  $\nu$ that are between the parentheses get symmetrized:

$$
g_{\sigma(\mu}{\Gamma^{\sigma}}_{,\nu)}=\frac{1}{2}(
g_{\sigma\mu}{\Gamma^{\color{red}{\sigma}}}_{,\nu}+
g_{\sigma\nu}{\Gamma^{\color{red}{\sigma}}}_{,\mu}
).
$$

***Previous Answer***

There are three indices $\mu,\sigma,\nu$ between the symmetrization parentheses.
According to the link I gave
$$
g_{\sigma(\mu}{\Gamma^{\sigma}}_{,\nu)}=\frac{1}{3!}(
g_{\sigma\mu}{\Gamma^{\color{red}{\sigma}}}_{,\color{lightgreen}{\nu}}+
g_{\sigma\mu}{\Gamma^{\color{lightgreen}{\nu}}}_{,\color{red}{\sigma}}+
g_{\sigma\color{lightgreen}{\nu}}{\Gamma^{\color{red}{\sigma}}}_{,\mu}+
g_{\sigma\color{lightgreen}{\nu}}{\Gamma^{\mu}}_{,\color{red}{\sigma}}+
g_{\sigma\color{red}{\sigma}}{\Gamma^{\mu}}_{,\color{lightgreen}{\nu}}+
g_{\sigma\color{red}{\sigma}}{\Gamma^{\color{lightgreen}{\nu}}}_{,\mu})\,.
$$
Just use all permutations of $\mu,\sigma,\nu\,.$